# Take a variables into array and find maximun value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, variables, max

Using numpy I have this variables:

```
A01 = 10  
A02 = 8  
A03 = 3  
A04 = 4  
A05 = 12
```

And this comparisons

```
C01 = abs(A01-A02)
C02 = abs(A01-A03)
C03 = abs(A01-A04)
C04 = abs(A01-A05)
C05 = abs(A01-A06)
```

I need take C01, C02, C03, C04, C05 into array and find maximun value, How I to do this? My objetive is find the maximum value of comparisons based on the list of variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an array with those variables, and compare the first index to the rest via slicing. Then you can use `np.abs` and `np.max` to evaluate the entire array.

```
import numpy as np
A0, A1, A2, A3, A4 = 10, 8, 3, 4, 12
compare = np.array([A0, A1, A2, A3, A4])
max_val = np.max(np.abs(compare[0]-compare[1:]))
print(max_val) #Should be 7
```